# CUPS printer on Vritual Machine can be access via CUPS admin, but not by XP?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, printer, cups

I have a Zebra label printer connected to a Linux Mint virtual machine. It was set up with CUPS and a Windows XP computer can then print to it via http://192.168.1.76:632/printers/labelprinter. That was all fine and dandy

I then hooked up a Fargo Pro L PVC card printer to a Windows XP virtual machine. I had to disconnect the label printer as the server that hosted both virtual machines only has 1 parallel port. Now I plugged in the Zebra again, and it cannot print from the Windows XP computer anymore. If I go to the CUPS admin panel on the Windows XP computer, I can see it, everything looks fine, and I can send it a test page to print which works. If I try to print from Windows, I get an error that the printer is not found/cannot connect to the server.

The only other thing that changed was the firewall on the router to allow remote desktop to another computer from outside the network, but all the firewall stuff was for external use. Nothing affected the IP address of the internal network. The Linux Mint VM also had a PDF pritner that was shared with CUPS. That printer is also down. I tried setting up a new CUPS installation on another VM, and when I go to share it with XP, I get the same error.

I don't know what to try. It has access, it can get to the admin from that computer, it seems to be up and ready, but when Windows tries to connect, the printer isn't found even though 4 days ago everything was fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried connecting to the CUPS printer from another XP machine, and it worked fine. I couldn't find nay differences between services running or anything else that was different between the two XP computers. The only thing I could find about connecting to a CUPS printer from XP was to install it as a local computer with a new local port. The new port would actually be the URL to the printer. I tried these even though the printer used to work with it installed as a network printer and the other XP computer had it installed as a network printer. After I entered in the URL for the port, an error popped up saying it was an invalid port name. I tried it again without the http://, and it was still invalid.

I couldn't get it to install, so I went to the properties of the printer that was installed as a network printer. The properties opened up, which it wasn't doing before. I then tried sending a test page, and it worked, and then I tried using it, and it worked fine.

I have no idea why the printer quit working or what exactly made it start working again, but the printer is working correctly now.